# Same filter for 2 ng-repeats only works in one of them, AngularJS (?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search box where I am trying to filter 2 things but only one is filtering properly.

I have this:

```
<!--this is the input-->
<input type="search" placeholder="Sports finder" ng-model="query">
<!--this is the filter working-->
<div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:query"
     ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
<!--this is the one which is not working-->
<div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues">
```

and I already tried by doing:

```
<div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query">
```

someone says that the filter is not working because the last one is returning an object instead of an array.

here is the code where I am extracting the type:

```
AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
  $scope.customer = customer;
  SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    if (sports.length) {
      $scope.sports = sports;
      console.log($scope.sports);
      console.log('on controller js I am an ' + typeof($scope.sports));
    }else {
      AuthFactory.logout();
    }
```

the first console log returns:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

and the second one:

```
on controller js I am an object
```

Let's, say that I open that data you see there, then, once is open is returning this:

```
>0: Object
>1: Object
>2: Object
>3: Object
>4: Object
>5: Object
```

now let's open that `>0: Object` which returns:

```
$$hashKey: "object:54"
checked: true
id: 26
> leagues: Array[3]
name: 'Live Betting'
priority: 0
> proto: Object
```

and here is the thing: my filter works properly on the first `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]` but I also need to have it working there where see `leagues: Array[3]` which if I open it returns:

```
>0: Object
>1: Object
>2: Object
```

if you did not get that, see it on screenshots:

http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0121/h_1421875540_4177075_1b0b871a32.png

and:

http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/15/0121/h_1421875594_6426465_3e908c6363.png

is actually very weird, [I have a Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FJ45nV6gdwp3SkRglPeW?p=preview), which is working properly as I expect and I did it with a Json that I copied from my network console.

For example: if you type **International** or **Greece** you will see the filter returning:

```
International Basketball
GREECE A1
```

but in my app, if you type **International** the filter returns what I need which is the same above, if I type just **Greece** then the filter will not return anything.

**UPDATE**

Look at this Plunkr, is not working at all but at least you can see my full code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bfU8ynzmsQZk57dYXFUj?p=preview

Comment: How are you generating the json in your app?

Comment: Are you building that model? My guess is that the `leagues` are being added in somewhere by you (the `$$hashkey` is a giveaway). I'm thinking that `leagues` are not defined when the `ng-repeat` is called but the object will automatically update by the time you `console.log()` it- I have had that happen before. If so, can you use a breakpoint to try to see what is being passed to the filter? Or even at the point where you are logging $scope.sports to see if $scope.sports.leagues is actually undefined.

Comment: oh, I just did ```console.log($scope.sports.leagues);``` and returns ```undefined``` @idotpdot

Comment: if `$scope.sports` is array, `$scope.sports.leagues` should be undefined

Comment: check whether the angular version is the same in plunk and your app or not ?

Comment: Good point @charlietfl, trying doing something like `$scope.sports[0].leagues` instead.

Comment: @أنيسبوهاشم actually is the same, that is not the issue I have.

Comment: @idotpdot where do I have to tried ?

Comment: @TheUnnamed he means at  console.log($scope.sports); But I think that might be not the issue.

Comment: @idotpdot if I ```console.log(angular.toJson($scope.sports[0].leagues, true));``` I got this : http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0121/h_1421878962_3010753_8b34a79888.png

Comment: @TheUnnamed Is there any way you can post a Plunkr that better matches your code? Especially when it comes to how to you are building your $scope.sports. Something tells me you are doing two asynchronous requests and the one that is adding "leagues" has not returned in time for the filter, but in time for it show up with `console.log()`. Is that the case?

Comment: @idotpdot  
this version is not working at all, but here you can see my full code at least: http://plnkr.co/edit/bfU8ynzmsQZk57dYXFUj?p=preview

Comment: @TheUnnamed this is much better- I can see some code is missing still, but I'd recommend editing your question to show some of this code and this Plunkr, I think other devs would have an easier time helping you. You have a few calls being made here- so I can bet it has something to do with `leagues` not being ready at filter time, thus why your static model in your first Plunkr worked so well.

Comment: @idotpdot just update my question with missing code. And thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem. I would dig into your `getSportsWithLeagues` function. Try logging out some of the data in there, specifically around between line 54 and 62 of service.js in your not-working Plunkr.

Comment: http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/15/0121/h_1421882584_9138736_5c17306fbc.png on line 61 ```console.log(angular.toJson(sports, true));```

Comment: Hey @TheUnnamed I noticed that in your "working" simplified Plunkr and "non-working" Plunkr and your original source code, you're not being consistent with $scope.sports. In your "working" one, you clearly create it as an array of objects. In your "non working" one, you are creating it as an object of objects. In your original source code, you actually define `$scope.sports = {};` at the top of your controller. You should define it as `$scope.sports = [];`. You should normalize these in your demos and your local code to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @idotpdot I have it this way in my code ```$scope.sports = [];``` and still the same :(

Comment: Curious @TheUnnamed, did you ever manage to figure out what the issue was due to?

Comment: @idotpdot no bro. i still have it. I realized that both are arrays so there is no problem with the filters on that side. it seems to be as if something is loading after the filters get called. I've been with this task for the last week. still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think console.log might fool you. When you click the object in console to check its property. It shows the property it has when you click it not the moment you print it.

try this. `console.log(angular.toJson($scope.sports, true));`

so you can see what exact do you have at that moment.

Comment: return this: http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0121/h_1421878266_6963279_dfe124b6bb.png

Comment: **EDIT:**
return this: http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0121/h_1421878634_3377919_dcf8291b30.png

Sorry bro, look at it now.

Comment: someone says is because is an object instead of array

Comment: huh ? it works fine in Plunker. Besides, sports is Array and leagues is Array too. [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not the way to check if it is array or obj.  Use angular.isArray instead.

Comment: yes. if I ```console.log('on controller js I am an ' + angular.isArray($scope.sports));``` the result is ```true```

Comment: This kinda sh1t happens. My experience tells me you are looking at the wrong thing. It is not because of filter or anything. Sometime it might be causing by typo or other stuff that you don't expect.

Comment: this version is not working at all, but here you can see my full code http://plnkr.co/edit/bfU8ynzmsQZk57dYXFUj?p=catalogue

Comment: I read it thru. I don't see anything weird right away. sorry man.